# Click event in an inactive window

Tags: click, mouseevent, tidesdk

So lets say I have created two windows via the Ti.UI.createWindow() method,and I have a close window button on both windows. The first window is the current window.

I click the second window's close button and instead of closing the second window, it takes focus. I have to click the second window's close button again once it is active to close the window.

Is there any way of being able to click the button even if the window does not have focus or somehow pass the click event through so it not only takes focus but also inherits the click event for the button? Thanks.